# Need to reach a field that is nested in arrays MongoDB

Tags: javascript, arrays, node.js, mongodb, sorting

I'm using aggregation. I need to make a new field with the $addFields operator, the field value that I'm trying to reach is in the first field of the array that is the nested in the first array, I am of need to convert that string value into a date format.

I've tried to use the following with no success so far, I tried playing with the $ operator with no luck, I need to make it work in this form can't use no projection or other kids of operations. When I just do **$jobs.periods.hireDate** i see the field but in a belly of the array **[[hireDate]]** :

```
The format is:
array[
  array[0]: stringField
]


$addFields: {
 hireDate: {
  $dateFromString: {
    dateString: '$jobs.$.periods.0.hireDate'
  }
 }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

try this this might work

`

```
   $addFields: {
     hireDate: {
      $dateFromString: {
      dateString: 'jobs.periods.0.hireDate'
     }
    }
```

`

Comment: It doesn't work that way, it shoots out an error.

**Error parsing date string 'jobs.periods.0.hireDate'; 0: passing a time zone identifier as part of the string is not allowed 'j'; 11: Double timezone specification 's';**